# Cascode: Which device goes into triode region first?

Tags: mosfet, analog, cmos, saturation, cascode

[image]

In the above cascode network, which device goes into triode region first, if the supply gradually decreases?

Framing the question other way round, if the supply gradually increases from 0V, which device goes into saturation first?

My intuition is that the cascode device M2 in saturation has the ability to shield M1 from supply variation, and when looking at former version of question, it seems M2 will go into triode region first. This is vague, with a simple small signal analysis and I am unable to reason same in 2nd version of the question.

Someone help me figuring this out.

Both intuition and analysis are appreciated.

Comment: Well... what defines whether the devices are in triode or saturation mode?

Answer (score 1):

*My intuition is that the cascode device M2 in saturation has the ability to shield M1 from supply variation, and when looking at former version of question, it seems M2 will go into triode region first.*

I would agree that the top device provides some ability to shield M1 (Drain voltage) from supply variation (look at pink vout1 curve), this is only since the fixed VG and VGS of M2 acts like a clamp for the VDS of M1. As VDS is freely dropping on M2 (light blue curve), the VDS of M1 stays fixed by the fixed VGS curve of M1. You can see this in a plot of the simulation, where M1 appears fixed (lambda was fixed to zero for purposes of discussion).

At a certain point as Vout keeps dropping M2 VDS will equal M1 VDS, right before they both drop out of saturation and the overall Id curve starts to transition between linear and saturation region. I would argue that M2 VGS (light grey curve) is getting bigger as VDS of M1 is dropping, and so M2 has a steeper linear slope on a higher VGS curve causing it to hit triode region slightly faster until M1 catches up. But, really they are both moving to triode, it is just M1 will get there slightly slower.

The same reasoning will apply in the other direction (vout increasing from 0).

It will be very tricky to model this analytically, as the region between linear and saturation is modelled by interpolation.

[image]